# How can a evenly spaced grid with a circular boundary be modeled?

Tags: modeling

I can't loop cut a circle and if I use the knife tool to go across the vertices the edges won't be evenly spread.
I was originally thinking of loop cutting the circle, beveling those edges and then deleting the faces in between, but that proved impossible very quickly.

My next thought was to use a plane and use the knife project to cut a circle out from it, but stupid me then realized I would need the area AROUND the circle to be deleted from the plane and not the circle itself. Haven't worked with many circles (obviously).

Any guidance here would REALLY be appreciated. I'm totally stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Grid first, then cut it by [Knife Projecting](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html#knife-project) a circle.

I would start by modeling the evenly spaced grid with a couple of **Array modifier** (one to repeat the geometry on the X axis and one on the Y). Check the Merge boxes to avoid obtain disconnected geometry.

[image]

Apply the two modifiers, then create the circle and **Knife project** it on the grid.

[image]

Invert selection and delete the unwanted faces. Now **Inset** the faces **individually**, **Extrude**, **Mirror** the result, and so on...

[image]

In my example I also **Beveled** the edges and added a **Lattice** modifier after some **Simple Subdivison** iterations as you can see in the modifier tab on the right.

[image]

---

**Bonus**:

You **can** loopcut a circle's faces if you model them properly (no tris, axial edge flow) as shown in the gif below:

[image]

but it would be trickyer to get an evely spaced grid because of the vertices distribution along the circle. That's why is better to model the grid first.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that. I'm going to have to do some research on what almost all the modifiers you listed are. When you say "I would start by modeling the evenly spaced grid" should I model that using a plane? I just tried an array modifier, but it's only copying the grid once. How did you go through that step? Thanks again. Really a big help. You are VERY talented.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You'll need not one but two Array modifiers. I've edited the answer in this sense. Add a plane, scale it on an axis to get a rectangle and then you are ready to start.

Comment: Perfect I'll try this out thanks again I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Boolean operations to construct the shape?  You could start with a (hi-res) solidified UV sphere and slice of the top to make the general shape.  Then, using an array modifier and some scales cubes create a lattice-like structure that you can difference from the sphere.  The resulting geometry will likely be pretty horrible though with poor topology so you may need to do a lot of hand clean up if you want to subsurf it, for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with boolean operations, but have heard it mentioned before. So many hurdles with this program!!! I love it and hate it at the same time! I can't believe how complex it can be. I'm not too sure what you just said, but I will definitely do some research on it. Thank you for posting!