# Create a circle from a plane

Tags: modeling

So new to blender if this is super easy my bad.

I have created a plane with lots of small holes in it to replicate the mesh on the front of a speaker by subdividing a plane and using the Wireframe and Subdivision Modifiers. Creating this
[image: speaker mesh]
 I want a circle shape not a square though how can I get the above image to be on a flat circle rather than a flat square to be like this but with my first pictures design not the hex pattern[image: what im trying to do]

I hope this edit cleared it up a bit

Comment: Could you please be more specific or describe it in another way? I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: If you started with a square and then your first modifier is a subdivision, it should be round already. So why cut a circle out of it?

Comment: My first instinct was to intersect your mesh with a cylinder using the Boolean modifier, but it seems that the topology is too complicated for the modifier to compute correctly. Even when I applied the wireframe and subsurface modifiers added polygons to the edges to turn the mesh into a manifold: the boolean operator malfunctions.

Comment: It is clear from the answers given that your question is open to different interpretations. Can you please edit the text and clarify what you want to do? If you have an image illustrating the desired result it would help a lot.

Comment: Started with a plane then used subdivide tool to create smaller sections then added wireframe modifier then added sub surf

Comment: related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-create-a-circular-shaped-grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover/58860#58860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a hexagonal torus with two array modifiers to create the mesh then I just used the Boolean modifier to cut it out.  It's dirty but quick and easy:

[image]

Use ***Circle Select*** to select the extremities and proportional editing to slope the curve downward:

[image]

Finally, I added a "rubber" grommet around the edge:

[image]

Comment: Ok I thought boolean could only be used to remove a hole from the mesh not take a peice of it thanks man

Comment: Hey no problem.  The Boolean mod actually has three different operations.

Comment: Whats the third if you don't mind me asking here

Comment: No not at all, but it would be more beneficial for you to see it work: https://youtu.be/pcUe-ab_jQs?t=54

Comment: Cheers mate very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the top ortho mode

Take a plane sub divide to 15

rotate in x axis

move little in y axis

Type warp in space bar

and get this settings 180,0,-1,1

Now rotate in y axis

type warp in space bar

and get this settings 360,0,-1,1

Now you get a perfect sphere

[image]