# Cutting the Ends of an Array

Tags: modifiers

I'm attempting to make what I believe is called a lattice fence, as one would see at the base of a raised house.

I used an array modifier to duplicate the "X" rectangles. I'm trying to cut off the ends of the non-complete lattice portions. I tried a Boolean modifier - which of course does not work.

Any ideas as to how I may proceed is appreciated. Should I forget about the array and just duplicate and space the "X"s?

The mage shows a face and an 80 deg. view.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the Boolean "of course did not work"?  It should work fine for this.  You may have to clean up the remaining geometry though.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84995/create-a-circle-from-a-plane/85055#85055

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did a Boolean/Difference, and at the time I must have done something wrong so made that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean does the trick if you use the right object. You can also use an array modifier for the cutting object to have the same pattern without adjusting manually.
(In my example I switched to carve solver)
[image]

Comment: You don't really have to get that complicated.  You can just make a rectangle.  Lattice panels are usually just ripped on all four sides: https://www.lowes.com/pd/4-x-8-Plastic-Lattice-Panel-Redwood/1016347